# Calculating the surface of a captured video object using ImageJ

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, imagej

I'm a relative newbie when it concerns image analysis. My PhD advisor introduced a question regarding calculating the surface area of the forearm of pain patients who cannot stand even the lightest touch on their skin.

Therefore, I'd like to find out is whether or not the following is feasible:

My idea is mounting a small video camera unto a pod which is placed on a circular rail (like that of a toy train) far enough from the forearm so it can capture its whole length.

The participant will then place their forearm in the middle of this "capturing circle", and the camera will be circled to capture a 360 view of the forearm.

The video will be then fed into ImageJ/Fiji for pre-processing, eventually to be rendered as a 3D-object which surface and volume can be calculated and further used for analysis.

I'd appreciate your expert opinions on this, and any help/recommendation will be welcome.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: As there are few features to be seen on a clean skin, stereoscopy alone won't work. You'll probably need to use structured light.

Comment: what's the desired accuracy and purpose for this? for most applications it should suffice to estimate the surface area from 1-2 images